# Qual è la differenza nel significato di queste parole per "sorry" in italiano?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-choice, difference

- Spiacente
- Dispiace
- Scusi

What are the precise contexts of the word usage of the aforementioned words for sorry?

Grazie

Comment: “Mi dispiace”, non “Dispiace”.

Answer (score 5):

I look at http://www.wordreference.com/enit/sorry to clarify the different usage of the italian words you mention:

- *"Spiacente"* and *"Mi dispiace"* are pretty equivalent, and are used with "regretful" or "sympathetic" meaning.

Examples:

"I am sorry that you were sick" = "Mi dispiace che tu fossi malato".

"Sorry, but we sold out the tickets" = "Mi dispiace, i biglietti sono finiti". Please note that this example is more formal and you can as well use "Spiacente" ("Spiacente, i biglietti sono finiti")

- *"Scusi"* or *"Mi scusi"* when are used at the beginning of the phrase like an introduction, have the meaning of "Excuse me" or "please repeat"

Examples:

"Excuse me, sir; may I ask you something?" = "Mi scusi, posso farle una domanda?".

"Sorry? I have not understood" = "Scusi? Non ho capito".

When used alone, "Scusi" has the same meaning of "My apologies", and can be replaced with "Mi dispiace" (but "Scusi" is more polite).

Comment: "Spiacente" is a little bit more formal than "mi dispiace". Have a look at: http://www.linkiesta.it/it/article/2015/12/12/mi-spiace-o-mi-dispiace-lo-spiega-la-crusca/28554/.

Comment: And how about this expression: "Scusi posso" ? Grazie tanto

Comment: "Scusi, posso"  = "Excuse me, may I...."